# Powershell Replace '"`n' don't work

Tags: powershell, replace

i need to replace with powershell the String

```
`"`n  (`n = Line feed)`
```

in ";" as exsample, but

```
`(Get-Content $file -raw).replace('"`n', ';')| Set-Content $filenew -force`
```

doesn't work

Can someone help me? Thanks.

feva

Answer (score 0):

This is a line feed:

```
`n
```

So you're close!

## Example

```
$input = @"
one
two
three
"@

$input -replace "`n", ";"
```

### Results

```
one;two;three
```

## Your Code

```
(Get-Content $file -Raw).Replace('`n', ';') |
    Set-Content $filenew -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is the " in front of `n
The String is "`n include the "

```
$input -replace ""`n", ";"
```

will not work.